# Разобраться в настройках joerc

Tags: bash, freebsd

Программист оставил такой код:

```
 joe /usr/local/etc/joe/joerc  
 ^kf linums   
 *--wordwrap -linums   
 rc -linums   
 ^kx
```

Как я понимаю:

1. Cтрочка открыть joerc
2. Найти linums
3. Написать указанную строку
4. Удалить строку -linums
5. Сохранить изменения

Прошу прокомментировать - правильно ли я понял ? 
С joe не работал, писавшего не достать.

Comment: Я с joe тоже не работал, но судя по приведенным буковкам -- вряд ли.

Тут почти наверняка правится стандартный конфиг этого редактора. Судя по всему `rc` это какая-то его (конфига) директива, относящияся к опции `-linums` (думаю, это связано с нумерацией строк).

Видимо это тоже текст, который надо набить (вместе с п. 3).

А вот Ctrl-kf -- поиск и Ctrl-kx -- сохранить, это похоже.

--

Вообще, лучше почитайте что-нибудь типа `man joe`.

и посмотрите на остальной текст конфига, наверное длгадаетесь, каким он должен быть.

В крайнем случае отредактируйте его vi (его-то знаете?)

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правильно поняли.
Программист к стандартным настройкам джо добавляет вывод номера строки в каждой строчке и отключает перенос строк при достижении края окна.
У меня обычно ещё такие опции: -nobackups --autoindent -tab 4.

Читайте man :)